# Synchronous AFNetworking operations and parsing

Tags: ios, afnetworking, nsoperationqueue

I am stuck in serially Execution of Afnetworking Operation. Currently I am able to get all the operations' response but those are not serially . I need to make it serial.

What I am doing is

```
    for (int i = 0; i < myArray.count; i++) {
            //Creating Soap Request
            // Adding that SoapRequest to Operation
                AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];
                [operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        // On success I am parsing the response
// Parsing is executed here..
        } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    // Failure message
        }

// If Network is reachable then adding the Operation in queue
        [[PFAPIClient sharedClient] enqueueHTTPRequestOperation:operation];
        // Adding the operation (For multiple execution of operations) 

        }
```

Thus the response I get is not serial . Please Help me out. 
So How to get this response serially and parsing the response accordingly .. After successfully Parsing I have to display them..

Answer (score 0):

You can either set `maxConcurrentOperationCount` of `PFAPIClient`'s `NSOperationQueue` to `1` or you can use dependencies, e.g.:

```
AFHTTPRequestOperation *previousOperation = nil;

for (int i = 0; i < myArray.count; i++) {
    AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];
    [operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:... failure:...];
    if (previousOperation) {
        [operation addDependency:previousOperation];
    }

    [[PFAPIClient sharedClient] enqueueHTTPRequestOperation:operation];

    previousOperation = operation;
}
```

It's too bad you have to do these sequentially, as you'll pay huge performance penalty, but if you have to do it, that's two ways to accomplish it.

Comment: I have added all the operations in operation queue and set maximum concurrent operation count to 1. It worked for me .. @Rob Thanks for the reply !!